Flutter Web - Browser Refresh Button
I am using Flutter for developing a website. Everything is working fine with Flutter except when it comes to reloading the page. When I press the refresh button in the browser, then the data is not getting reloaded , only the shimmer that i have added to be shown before the data loads keep showing infinitely.
How to manage refresh when the browser's refresh button is clicked? Can we manage it via code?
We tried to do "html.window.location.reload();" , this is going into an infinite loop of reload.

How about navigating to the same page but not reloading the page?

try Wrapping your data fetching logic within a Future Builder
